# stored procedure with if else sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables, I have to check if grandparent table id has records in grandchildren table. If yes, return yes, else return no. Here is my stored procedure. I got an incorrect syntax error. I am new to stored procedure. Please help me.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_Check
   @PKG_ID INT,
   @S_ID INT,
   @FLAG VCHAR(10) OUT

   DECLARE IDS CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT S_ID FROM T1 WHERE P_ID = @PKG_ID
   OPEN IDS
   FETCH NEXT FROM IDS into @S_ID

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE S_ID = @S_ID

      IF @@ROWCOUNT<>0
         @FLAG = 'YES'
         RETURN 
      ELSE
         @FLAG = 'NO'

      FETCH NEXT FROM IDS into @S_ID
   END

   CLOSE IDS
   DEALLOCATE IDS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. I don't think there is a `vchar` data type in SQL Server unless that is your custom type. So change it to `varchar`
2. You forgot the `AS`
3. You might want to enclose your logic inside `if` in between `begin` and `end`

Your code that can be compiled:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_Check
    @PKG_ID INT,
    @S_ID INT,
    @FLAG VARCHAR(10) OUT
AS
    DECLARE IDS CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT S_ID FROM T1 WHERE P_ID = @PKG_ID
    OPEN IDS
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDS into @S_ID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE S_ID = @S_ID
      IF @@ROWCOUNT<>0
      BEGIN
         SET @FLAG = 'YES'
         RETURN 
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
         SET @FLAG = 'NO'
         FETCH NEXT FROM IDS into @S_ID
      END
    END

    CLOSE IDS
    DEALLOCATE IDS
```

However, I think your cursor will not be closed as you are returning here `IF @@ROWCOUNT<>0`. I think what you should do is change this:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT<>0
BEGIN
    SET @FLAG = 'YES'
    RETURN 
END
```

to this:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT<>0
BEGIN
    SET @FLAG = 'YES'
    GOTO ON_EXIT
END
```

then end your procedure like this:

```
ON_EXIT:
    CLOSE IDS
    DEALLOCATE IDS
```

Then to answer your question in the comment, you are "returning" it already in a sense. You can call and test your procedure like this:

```
declare @result varchar(10)
exec P_Check 1, 1, @result out
print @result
```

Comment: Is the same can achieve through just a join between t1 and t2 by matching S_ID?

Comment: I suggest you go with @marc_s' answer. Your question was originally with a syntax error, and optimizing it is another thing. Marc_s' answer is a good alternative.

Answer (score 3):

This is just way too complicated and using a cursor here is totally not needed and totally unnecessary.

Simplify your procedure to be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_Check
   @PKG_ID INT,
   @S_ID INT,
   @FLAG CHAR(1) OUT
AS BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 
              INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.S_ID = T1.S_ID WHERE P_ID = @PKG_ID)
      SET @FLAG = 'Y'
   ELSE
      SET @FLAG = 'N'
END
```

When working seriously with SQL Server, you need to get away from the procedural **row-by-agonizing-row** thinking using cursors and loops, and you need to start **thinking in sets** to be efficient and productive.